# How to use react-datetime with react + typescript (inside tsx)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-datetime

[`react-datetime`](https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime) has a typescript definition file included, but it does not work (for me). From what I can see, the [ts definition file](https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime/blob/f3584307689423e3bc810efee9d68e9a2aea9980/react-datetime.d.ts) exports a different type (`ReactDatetime`) than what is in actual [javascript file](https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime/blob/f3584307689423e3bc810efee9d68e9a2aea9980/DateTime.js) (`Datetime`).

I went ahead and changed `react-datetime.d.ts` typings file to export the (what I think) is correct type (available in [gist](https://gist.github.com/skyflyer/e3e4290616eb78b8fdf941495c370863)):

```
interface Datetime extends React.ComponentClass<DatetimepickerProps> {}
export { Datetime }
```

And TypeScript complains that it can not find the `Datetime`:

```
(26,10): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Datetime'.
```

I guess there's something pretty basic I must be missing in terms of typings and this component. Trying to make it work with the original typings file resulted in inability to import the module in the first place, even though the `react-datetime.d.ts` file was referenced using `/// <reference path="../node_modules/react-datetime/react-datetime.d.ts" />` directive.

A minimalistic example of class trying to use `<Datetime/>`:

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/react-datetime/react-datetime.d.ts" />
import * as React from "react";
import { Datetime } from "react-datetime";


export interface DateTimeResolutionProps { timestamp: number, resolution: number }
export class DateTimeResolutionPicker extends React.Component<DateTimeResolutionProps, {}> {
    render() {
        // console.log(Datetime);
        return (<div>
        <Datetime/>
        </div>);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should import it just like you imported the `React` module:

```
import * as Datetime from "react-datetime";
```

Then it won't complain about not finding the `Datetime`.

As for the names, you decide what the name will be, it can be `ReactDatetime` if you want:

```
import * as ReactDatetime from "react-datetime";
```

The same happens with the `React` module, if you look at the definition file it will show:

```
declare namespace __React {
    ...
}

declare module "react" {
    export = __React;
}
```

Comment: This advice is no longer accurate in the current version of typescript. You want `import Datetime from "react-datetime"`

If you use the import statement described here you will get "JSX element type 'Datetime' does not have any construct or call signatures"

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting `Datetime` as a type, even though a React component needs to be a value (whether it's an SFC, or a class). So that's why your version isn't working.

[The version on the repo](https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime/blob/f3584307689423e3bc810efee9d68e9a2aea9980/react-datetime.d.ts#L115-L118) currently defines it as a CommonJS module, which means that for now it should be required with CommonJS-compatible syntax:

```
import Datetime = require("react-datetime");
```